# Error with Numerical Integration and Graph Plotting

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
β = 1;
ωc = 15;
G = 0.01;

integral4 := 
G ω Exp[-ω/ωc] ((
1 - Cos[ω τ] )/ω^2 ) Coth [βω/2]

Plot[ - (1/τ) Log[
1/2 + 1/2 Exp[ -    
   NIntegrate[integral4, {ω, 0, 70000}, 
    Method -> "LocalAdaptive", MaxRecursion -> 15]] ], {τ, 0,
3}]
```

But I get the errors:

1. NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand integral4 has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,70000}}. >>
2. NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand integral4 has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0,70000}}. >>
3. NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand integral4 has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{0.,70000.}}. >>
4. General::stop: Further output of NIntegrate::inumr will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

How do I get around it?

Comment: You should be using `Cos[]` and `Coth[]` (capitalization matters!) and square brackets, not parentheses. Please do read the docs on how to use these functions.

Comment: I made the edits and now I'm getting as my output: "0." This doesnt make sense.

Comment: Please edit your post to show the edited version you speak of.

Comment: Edited. Same error with the suggestions you suggested.

Comment: Try it with `NIntegrate[G ω Exp[-ω/ωc] ((1 - Cos[ω τ])/ω^2) Coth[βω/2], {ω, 0, 70000}]`. Do not use square brackets for grouping, as they are intended for functions. That is when you use parentheses.

Comment: Same error.

I have edited my post for the eventual command I want to run

Comment: The natural logarithm in *Mathematica* is `Log[]`. Really, you will need to read the docs first before anything else; you seem to have ignored my comment on not using square brackets for grouping. So, `Ln[(1/2)[1 + cx]]` is wrong; `Log[(1/2)(1 + cx)]` is correct.

Comment: I have re-edited the post using the eventual nested command I want to run. But it is still giving an error.

Comment: ...question: **did you notice the square bracket after `(1/2)` in your code**?

Comment: Hi, please check the edited post where I have hopefully removed the errors involving brackets.

Comment: Micheal E2, please see the edited post.

Comment: Any ideas, Micheal?

Comment: I corrected the ^2 error. I'm now getting an even horrendous list of errors.

What about the NumericQ command?

Comment: What do you mean? Eventually, I want to plot the function for tau and I'm specifying the range etc. for tau when I try and plot it. :/. Even when I remove tau from the expression for integral 4, I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces matter. If we check the OP's `integral4` we find in the output an undefined symbol `βω`.  Probably it was meant to be a `β ω`, meaning `β * ω`.

```
integral4 := G ω Exp[-ω/ωc] ((1 - Cos[ω τ])/ω^2) Coth[βω/2]

integral4
(*
  (0.01 E^(-ω/15) (1 - Cos[τ ω]) Coth[βω/2])/ω
*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
integral4 = G ω Exp[-ω/ωc] ((1 - Cos[ω τ])/ω^(2)) Coth[β ω/2];

Plot[-(1/τ) Log[
   1/2 + 1/2 Exp[-NIntegrate[integral4, {ω, 0, 70000}, 
        Method -> "LocalAdaptive", MaxRecursion -> 15]]],
 {τ, 0, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

By the way, the way I usually check a `NIntegrate::inumr` error is to evaluate the integrand at a value in the interval (use a real number with a decimal point):

```
integral4 /. ω -> 0.1    (* using OP's definition of integral4 *)
(*  0.0993356 (1 - Cos[0.1 τ]) Coth[βω/2]  *)
```

You can see I don't get a number and I see that `βω` does not have a numeric value.  You can also see `τ` is not numeric either, but here it's important to understand the order of evaluation.  `Plot` holds its argument; the variable `τ` is set to a value temporarily; then `Plot` releases its hold and the argument is evaluated (at this point `τ` has a numeric value and `NIntegrate` evaluates without error).

Comment: Hi Micheal E2. Thanks, you're a life saver. I'll try and run the command on Mathematica.

I'm having a torrid time with time. I need it for my physics project and I went through a one hour tutorial (lists, strings etc.) online and I started figuring out how to use it for my purposes. Any idea how I can better tackle it for my purposes? Is there an effective method to the madness because I have no experience with programming.

Comment: Somehow I suspect that `70000` is supposed to be `∞`, but @Junaid should be the one to confirm...

Comment: Yeah, my instructor just told me to use a very large number when dealling with infinities.

Comment: Sometimes replacing infinity with a large number is a good approach to numerical integrals.  Other times, it prevents a transformation from an infinite to finite range.  Certainly, you should choose a finite upper limit based on where your function becomes negligible...

Comment: @JunaidAftab `NIntegrate[integral4, {\[Omega], 0, Infinity}]` works just fine without any fancy stuff. Partly you'll get used to the syntax **if** you learn that every distinct character has a distinct meaning (e.g. `(`, `[`, spaces, etc.).  Plotting integrals and derivatives seems to be tricky for new users. (We get lots of questions.)  Otherwise, play with the examples in the documentation.  There's no really quick way to learn a new system as complicated and powerful as *Mathematica*.

Comment: @Junaid, in the case of *Mathematica*, `NIntegrate[]` has special methods for dealing with integrals with infinite limits; by making that replacement, you aren't getting the benefit of those methods.

Comment: @MichealE2, you edited your post by removing the "_Numeric"/"Block" solution to the problem. This solution is much more simple since it does effectively the same without using the aforementioned commands.

1. What's the difference between the 2 answers; and
2. Can you send me the code involving the aforementioned commands because I'd like to try and figure it out

Comment: @JunaidAftab I mistakenly thought it was necessary.  Creating a function with something like `f[x_?NumericQ]` is a common protection when the function `f` is composed of numerical functions like `NIntegrate`. In effect, it turns out there's not much difference here.  You can see the previous code by clicking the "edited...ago" link in the center below the answer (above the comments).  It will be edit number 1 down at the bottom.